# Having issue with click events/memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following JavaScript code.

```
    var Foo = function () {
      $('body').on('click', '.btn', this.update.bind(this));
    };

    Foo.prototype = (function () {

      var update = function (e) {
        console.log('update');
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      return {
        update: update
      }

    })();

    new Foo();
    new Foo();
    new Foo();
```

I am creating 3 instances of `Foo` constructor. Inside constructor, I am attaching a click event to dom element. However, with this approach the click event is attached 3 times because I am creating 3 instance using new operator. **How can I make this work so that after creating 3 instance it only attach one click event to that dom element?**

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0kfdkz9m/)

Comment: Why would you need 3 instances ? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `Having issue with click events/memory leak` What??? This is really unclear what you are expecting regarding the fact you instanciate it 3 times so how would expect it to work differently. I guess your posted sample is just unrelevant to your real use case

Answer (score 1):

```
var Foo = function () {
$('body').off('click', '.btn');
$('body').on('click', '.btn', this.update.bind(this));
};
```

This removes the click event listener, then rebinds it. That way it is limited to one listener.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a memory leak. This is how jQuery works if you bind events multiple times. If you do something like that:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e){/*logic here*/});
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e){/*logic here*/});
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e){/*logic here*/});
```

It will attach the event 3 times. Why do you think that if you put this thing into a class and instantiate the class 3 times it will not attach the event.

A way to prevent this behaviour is to do something like that:

```
var Foo = function () {
  if(!Foo.instantiatedOnce) {
    $('body').on('click', '.btn', this.update.bind(this));
  }
  Foo.instantiatedOnce = true;
};

Foo.prototype = (function () {

  var update = function (e) {
    console.log('update');
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return {
    update: update
  }

})();

Foo.instantiatedOnce = false;

new Foo();
new Foo();
new Foo();
```

Doing something like that it is like simulating a static variable that is shared between instances.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
var binded = false;
var Foo = function () {
    if (!binded) {
        $('body').one('click', '.btn', this.update.bind(this));
        binded = true;
    }
};
```